# Python: functions returned by itemgetter() not working as expected in classes

Tags: python

The [operator.itemgetter()](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function works like this:

```
>>> import operator
>>> getseconditem = operator.itemgetter(1)
>>> ls = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> getseconditem(ls) 
'b'
```

**EDIT I've added this portion to highlight the inconsitency**

```
>>> def myitemgetter(item):
...     def g(obj):
...         return obj[item]
...     return g
>>> mygetseconditem = myitemgetter(1)
```

Now, I have this class

```
>>> class Items(object):
...     second = getseconditem
...     mysecond = mygetseconditem
...
...     def __init__(self, *items):
...         self.items = items
...
...     def __getitem__(self, i):
...         return self.items[i]
```

Accessing the second item with its index works

```
>>> obj = Items('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> obj[1] 
>>> 'b'
```

And so does accessing it via the `mysecond` method

```
>>> obj.mysecond()
'b'
```

But for some reason, using the `second()` method raises an exception

```
>>> obj.second()
TypeError: itemgetter expected 1 arguments, got 0
```

What gives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`obj.second` is the function `getseconditem`. A function which expects an argument to operate on. Since you call `obj.second` without any arguments the error you gave is raised. To solve it you can do `obj.second(obj.items)` or define `second` differently:

```
class Items(object):
    def __init__(self, *items):
        self.items = items

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.items[i]

    def second(self):
        return getseconditem(self.items)
```

**Edit**

It's clear what you mean now after you edited your question. I think what's going on here is that because `getseconditem` is not a *user-defined* function it does not get transformed to a method upon accessing `obj.second`. It simply stays a function. The following can be found in the [`docs`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

> Note that the transformation from function object to (unbound or
>   bound) method object happens each time the attribute is retrieved from
>   the class or instance. In some cases, a fruitful optimization is to
>   assign the attribute to a local variable and call that local variable.
>   **Also notice that this transformation only happens for user-defined
>   functions; other callable objects (and all non-callable objects) are
>   retrieved without transformation.**

Comment: Technically since its being called as a method it would usually get itself as an automatic option.  My guess is that attaching the function to the object in that way is causing the runtime to treat it as a " static" method.  There may be a decorator you could use to  force it to treat it as a method.

Comment: @Rob Wouters: I think my question is what then makes my assignment `mysecond=mygetseconditem` special. Why does that one work and the other doesn't?

Comment: @mike, I've edited my answer to add what I think is causing the discrepancy.

Comment: @RobWouters, Thanks it makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

the problem seem to be in the following:

```
>>> print (getseconditem, mygetseconditem)
(<operator.itemgetter object at 0x01EE5BD0>, <function g at 0x00504DB0>)
```

In other words, a function can be bound, but a callable can not.

Comment: This won't work because `getseconditem` will get passed the `class` and not the instance and can therefore not access `self.items` (or `self.__getitem__`).

Comment: @rob-wouters, good point! But the problem seems to be deeper.